# Express js request body is not excatcly i want

Tags: javascript, express

Im working on simple app that allows you to register new user. I managed to create fetch POST request and catch it with express app.post method. It works but the value that req.body is retruning is not plain object but something more that I want.

It's literally returning something like this : `{ '{"login":"fff","password":"sss"}': '' }`
But I want it to be just sth like this: `{"login":"fff","password":"sss"}`

Here is my client side code

```
function eventListener() {
    const formSubmit = document.querySelector('.register-form');
    const newUser = new Register();

    formSubmit.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        newUser.checkInputs();

        const form = e.target;
        const formData = new FormData(form)

        const userData = {
            login: formData.get('login'),
            password: formData.get('password'),
        }

        console.log(userData);

        fetch('/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(userData)
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);

            })

    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', eventListener)
```

And here is server code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');



const app = express();


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('static'))

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {

    console.log('ok');
    console.log(req.body);

    res.end();

})



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log('running...');

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't lie to the server:

> ```
> 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
> ```

You are sending JSON.

By telling the server you are NOT sending JSON, you are confusing it.

It is trying to parse it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Tell it you are sending JSON:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```